# I need help in making a count up counter with multiple inputs in Python2

Tags: python-2.7

Help, I have made a count up counter that works partially. I have 2 inputs and i want the counter to up by 1 when either of the input is triggered. From the code that i have made i can only make the counter count up when i have 1 input once i add in and triggered the 2nd input i get an error saying "Invalid literal for int() with base 10" here is my code please help.

```
from time import sleep
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import os


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

button1=40
button2=11

GPIO.setup(button1,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(button2,GPIO.IN,pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

while(1):
            if GPIO.input(button1)==0:
                    f = open("counter1.txt","r+")
                    counter = int(f.readline())
                    counter += 1
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.write(str(counter))
                    f.close()
                    print (counter)
                    sleep(1)

            if GPIO.input(button2)==0:
                    f = open("counter2.txt","r+")
                    counter = int(f.readline())
                    counter += 1
                    f.seek(0)
                    f.write(str(counter))
                    f.close()
                    print (counter)
                    sleep(1)

            else:
                    counter = 0
                    f = open("counter.txt","w+")
                    f.write(str(counter))
                    f.close()
                    print (counter)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: once i add in button2 this problem happens